# R data.frame:Transform the content of a character-column to rows

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

I have the following data.frame:

**WORDS SCORE**

```
word1,word2,word3        12
word4,word5,word6        9
```

I want to convert into the following format

**WORDS SCORE**

```
word1 12
word2 12
word3 12
word4 9
word5 9
word6 9
```

Seems like a really simple one, but couldn't figure it out with transpose...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a simpler solution, e.g. with the `reshape2` package, but the following should work:

```
dat <- read.table(text='
  words score
  word1,word2,word3 12
  word4,word5,word6,word7 9', 
  header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

wds <- strsplit(dat$words, ',')
score <- rep(dat$score, unlist(lapply(wds, length)))
out <- data.frame(word=unlist(wds), score=score, 
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

> out
   word score
1 word1    12
2 word2    12
3 word3    12
4 word4     9
5 word5     9
6 word6     9
7 word7     9
```

I modified your example data to demonstrate that it will also work for comma-separated strings that have different numbers of words.